# Como verificar se um arquivo XML é valido com PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Segundo entendi pelas respostas [desta pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191866/how-to-validate-xml-with-php), o [`XMLReader::isValid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.isvalid.php) verifica "apenas o nó atual, não o documento inteiro". O que isso quer dizer?

No caso quero validar se o xml é válido antes de fazer:

```
$meuXml = simplexml_load_string($meuXml);
```

Porque algumas vezes acho que o xml vem mal formado, então recebo um erro tipo:

> stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity:
>   line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<

Então basicamente a pergunta é : Qual a melhor forma de verificar se um documento `.xml` é válido utilizando PHP? Mas também gostaria de saber o que significa "a verificação apenas do nó atual, e não do documento inteiro".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta você fazer o tratamento de erros com essa mesma API de XML do PHP.

A função `simplexml_load_string` retorna `false` quando não consegue processar corretamente o XML, então basta analisar o retorno da função.

```
$meuXml = simplexml_load_string($meuXml);

if (!$meuXml) {
    die("Erro ao processar o XML");
}
```

Mas dependendo das configurações do seu servidor, a mensagem de *warning* será exibida no navegador. Para que ela não seja exibida, você pode informar que irá tratar isso internamente com a função `libxml_use_internal_errors` e `libxml_get_errors`:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$meuXml = simplexml_load_string($meuXml);

if (!$meuXml) {
    $erros = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($erros as $erro) {
        echo $erro->message, PHP_EOL;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Desta forma, se o XML não for válido, produziria uma saída:

```
Erro: Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

E você pode tratar os erros como desejar.

Comment: Anderson, neste caso já avalia o XML inteiro ou só um dos nós... btw não entendi ainda muito bem a questão dos nós, se puder dar uma breve explicação...

Comment: @gustavox O XML em `$meuXml` inteiro. O retorno de `libxml_get_errors` será um *array* com todos os erros.

Answer (score 2):

O XML é feito de vários nós, quando você utiliza a função `XMLReader::isValid()`, ele valida somente o nó passado por parâmetro e não os "sub nós" que esse nó contem.

O que você pode fazer é validar o XML junto com o seu XSD usando [DOMDocument::schemaValidate](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.schemavalidate.php).

Caso não tenha o xsd, você pode fazer um tratamento de exceção no `simplexml_load_string` e mostrar uma mensagem personalizada.

O que você pode fazer também, é checar a validade do documento no da [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) para averiguar se realmente o problema é o xml.